# Is there a way to use a NextJS Image using the image itself's dimensions?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

Let's say I have an image that is currently 500px x 500px

In my Image tag, is there a way to just default the image to that?

```js
import Image from "next/image";
.
.
.
<Image
  src="/image.jpg"
  width={xxx}
  height={xxx}
/>
```

Comment: You would need to store the image's width and height somewhere or calculate it in your code. There's various ways to do this, but because it's a literal file that you're referencing you will have to have some way of processing the file data to get the information you want

Answer (score 1):

Width and Height are also not required if you're statically importing

Considering this to be static import since you have used  `src="/image.jpg"` therefore,

> Next.js will automatically determine the width and height of your
> image based on the imported file. These values are used to prevent
> Cumulative Layout Shift while your image is loading

For more refer the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images)